# Get the x and y coordinates of touched point while application running in the background

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, touch, gesture

for research proposes I need to get the user touch point (x,y) on the screen, I have developed an application which is does that, but what I want to know is it possible to get the x and y and record them to agile while the application running in the background,so the application should record my touch when I type a message or use any other application.

Any little help would be appreciated

Many thanks

Comment: Nice attempt at ios keylogger :D

Comment: Touch events aren't delivered to a background application.  Or at least it's not exposed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't record touches outside your app. Don't know if it's possible with jailbreak but without that it is impossible.

Comment: thanks for your answer, have you got any clue if it possible with Android? thanks.

Comment: @Crazy I don't know. But if it is possible it's quite big security risk so I guess it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

No. The execution of your app will be suspended when it goes to background.

Comment: thanks for your answer, have you got any clue if it possible with Android? thanks

Comment: friend if you want to learn it about android you will get easier and faster answer if you will ask this question again for Android.